# Javascript TypeError not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I'm trying to write myself a slider with jQuery. But I'm a bit confused about Javascript.
I saved the first (later the clicked ) element in a var:

```
  var current = $('.slider-element').get(0);
```

Now I want to add a class to this element:

```
 current.addClass('slider-collapse');
```

Executing it, I get an error:

```
TypeError: current.addClass is not a function  
current.addClass('slider-collapse');
```

I'm sure that it's an easy thing.... But I don't get it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [`.get(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) will return a DOM element. But you want a jQuery Object, so you should use [`.eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

Try replace it

> current.addClass('slider-collapse');

to

> $(current).addClass('slider-collapse');

Comment: Re-invoking jQuery when all that's needed is to fix how it was invoked the first time, is a sign of someone without a clue what they're really doing.